# How to reflect a chrome sphere in a scene with a procedural texture

Tags: opengl, direct3d

My scene background is a procedural texture that draws an ocean, or a lava floor, or some such other background.  It extends completely under as well, as if you were inside a cubemap.  It would be easier if I could assume the view was the same in all directions, but if there's a sun, for example, you cannot.

Now if I wanted to put a chrome sphere in the middle, what does it reflect?  Does the sphere see the same thing as the main camera does?

Assume it's expensive to render the background, and I do not want to do it multiple times per frame.  I can save a copy to use in the reflection if that helps.

Can someone suggest a general approach?  Here's an example of the procedural texture I mean (this is all in the shader, no geometry other than a quad):

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtS3DD

Comment: I think what you're after is [environment mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping) (except that you should use your procedural textures instead of an image loaded from a file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: In the real world, the reflection you see in the sphere depends on both the position of the camera, and the position of the sphere itself. However, taking both positions into account is prohibitively expensive for a moving sphere when using cube mapping (the most common approach), since you have to re-render all six faces of the cubemap with each frame. Thus, most games "fake" reality by using a cubemap that is centered about the origin ((0, 0, 0) in world-space) and only rendering static objects (trees, etc.) into the cube map.

Since your background is entirely procedural, you can skip creating cubemap textures. If you can define your procedural background texture as function of direction (not position!) from the origin, then you can use normal vector of each point on the sphere, plus the sphere's position, plus the camera position to sample from your background texture.

Here's the formula for it, using some glsl pseudocode:

```
vec3 N = normal vector for point on sphere
vec3 V = position of camera
vec3 S = position of point on sphere

vec3 ray = normalize(reflect(V-S,N));
// Reflect the vector pointing from the a point on the sphere to 
// the camera over the normal vector for the sphere.

vec4 color = proceduralBackgroundFunc(ray);
```

Above, `color` is the final output of the shader for point `S` on the sphere's surface.

Alternatively, you can prerender the background into a cube texture, and then sample from it like so (changing only the last line of code from above):

```
vec4 color = texture(cubeSample,ray);
```